# MySQL Return Predefined Column Value as Int

Tags: java, mysql

I've got a mysql query that predefines a column in the query that is meant to be an integer type:

```
SELECT id, 1 AS item_id from table WHERE other_id = 1;
```

When I retrieve this statement in Java I get a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I've tried casting the value to an integer using the UNSIGNED type:

```
SELECT id, CAST(1 AS UNSIGNED) AS item_id from table WHERE other_id = 1;
```

But that gives me the same type of error:

```
java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I'm not sure if this is something I need to fix in Java or in the actual sql statement, but i'd like to get the value back as an Integer.

The only place in Java I can imagine in causing the problem could be that I am bringing the value in as an object because i'm storing the record as a hashmap and don't know the exact column type. Unfortunately I can't change this.

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
while(resultSet.next()) {
    HashMap<String, Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++) {
        row.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), resultSet.getObject(i));
    }
    list.add(row);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post the relevant Java code.

Comment: If you can get it as a `Float` (which seemed to be what you were getting), you can call [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intValue()) to get an `int`.

Comment: I can make it work that way. But just for curiosity sake is there no way to define the column as an int or do I just have to take what Java gives me when its converting it to an object?

Comment: I've never had `resultSet.getInt` not work when an `int` is what I was expecting. I don't know what you're doing to get ambiguously typed values.

Comment: I'm using getObject because i'm storing the column in a hashmap and I don't know the exact column type when i'm looping through the results. Reason i'm doing this is a long story but I need the values in a hashmap to work with other parts of the system.

Comment: use something like this: `int value = ((Number)rs.getObject("field")).intValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you "think" that the column must contain integers only, you should `UPDATE` your column within the table.

If you want a quick fix of this problem, just cast the received result within Java.

```
int a = (int) rs.getObject("item_id");
```

Comment: Weird part is I am casting to int in Java, but i'm getting the error posted above. The column is a virtual column created in the query so i'm not sure how to define that as an INT.

Comment: @ryandlf This is weird because I can not reproduce the problem here.

Comment: Take a look at the code I posted. I'm bringing the value in as an object and then casting to int later. Maybe that has something to do with it?